# Maria DB - Table with column of type Json

Tags: mysql, json

Create a table in MariaDB that supports Json type data.

**Code:**

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
    `id`  int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    `title`  varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
    `options`  json NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MariaDB does not support the `JSON` column type. Only MySQL 5.7+ does.

Comment: Any alternative to add Json in a table field?

Comment: Use MySQL 5.7 or as an alternative with much better JSON support, Postgres 9.5+.

Comment: I use xampp as a web server on my computer, and as I need php 5.6 +, I had to download a recent version of xampp and by default it comes with MariaDB, my solution so far, is to create a text type field and add the Json there. Well this?

Comment: That "works" but the JSON column type does offer some advantages.

Comment: If it is very true, but for now will be the solution, thank you.